# Send the user to my other apps, Windows Phone button

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

How can I give a code to the button "See my other apps on the Store" for my application?

I used:

```cs
    private void buttonMyOtherApps_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketPlaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketPlaceDetailTask.Show();
    }
```

But this opens the current app in the store, not the list of my apps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method, but you can perform a simple search over the marktplace and you will get all the apps from a developer by his name on the store.

```
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask(); 
marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "developer-username"; 
marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

Here a list of available Tasks you might look into: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/6-how-to-use-marketplace-tasks-in-a-wp7-app